# Check all colums for a value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has 4 fields for answers, named a1,a2,a3,a4.
some of them may be marked correct. I appended "-correct" to the correct answers.

Anyways, now the user when selects an answer, I want to compare to any of the correct answers.

I'm only familiar with the %LIKE% and WHERE functions. I'm trying to use the MATCH AGAINST.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Mike

PHP:

```
     public function checkAnswer($id, $answer){
     try{

        $_id = $this->db->mysqli->real_escape_string($id);
        $_answer = $this->db->mysqli->real_escape_string($answer);
        $viewer_answered = $_answer."-correct";

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM myTbl WHERE match(a1,a2,a3,a4) against('+ $viewer_answered' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND id='{$_id}'";
        $result = $this->db->mysqli->query($sql);

            if(!$result)
            {
                 throw new Exception("Query failed: " . $sql . " - " . $this->db->mysqli->error);
            }else{

              // I dont know how to check the result of the match! any help please

            }    


        } catch(Exception $e){
           echo("Message: " . $e->getMessage());
        }



}
```

Comment: Why not just have an additoinal field that stores the number of the correct field value.  Or better yet, why not normalize your data and have a questions table and an answers table with a one to many relationship?

Comment: `MATCH ... AGAINST` is for full text search. You need a full text index, but words are separated by white space, so this won't work for you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql string is incorrectly formatted :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTbl WHERE match(a1,a2,a3,a4) against('".$viewer_answered."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND id='{$_id}'";
```